# How do I write a While loop

Tags: language-agnostic, conditional-statements

How do you write the syntax for a While loop?

### C`#`

```
int i = 0; 
while (i != 10)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(i); 
   i++; 
}
```

### VB.Net

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
While i <> 10
    Console.WriteLine(i)
    i += 1
End While
```

### PHP

```
<?php
while(CONDITION)
{
//Do something here.
}
?>


<?php
//MySQL query stuff here
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die("Opps");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$_SESSION['fName'] = $row['fName'];
$_SESSION['lName'] = $row['lName'];
//...
}
?>
```

### Python

```
i = 0
while i != 10:
    print i
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP a while loop will look like this:

```
<?php
while(CONDITION)
{
//Do something here.
}
?>
```

A real world example of this might look something like this

```
<?php
//MySQL query stuff here
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die("Opps");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$_SESSION['fName'] = $row['fName'];
$_SESSION['lName'] = $row['lName'];
//...
}
?>
```

Comment: There is a reason. Wow. I feel better now.

Answer (score 5):

There may be a place for this type of question, but only if the answer is correct. `While` isn't a keyword in C#. `while` is. Also, the space between the `!` and `=` isn't valid. Try:

```
int i=0; 
while (i != 10)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(i); 
    i++; 
}
```

While I'm here, [Python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
i = 0
while i != 10:
    print i
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### TCL

```
set i 0
while {$i != 10} {
    puts $i
    incr i
}
```

C++, C, JavaScript, Java and a myriad of other C-like languages all look exactly the same as C#, except in the way that they write the output to the console, or possibly the way you create the variable `i`.  Answering that would belong in some other question.